# CSS vertical-alignment - what am I not understanding?

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

I'm messing around with everyone's favorite CSS topic, vertical alignment. I found a little case that makes no sense to me, which probably means I'm failing to understand something about CSS.

I have the following HTML (it's for exploration code, so please excuse the inline styles):

```
<div style="height: 40px; line-height: 40px; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 1em 2em;">
    <span style="background-color: Blue; height: 30px; width: 30px; margin: 5px 1em; display:inline-block;"> </span>
    <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

This displays a blue box and some text, both vertically centered. But if I replace the `&nbsp;` with a regular space character, the text in the other span is no longer centered. I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFryV/1/) that demonstrates this.

My question is - why does changing from an `&nbsp;` to a space character in the first span change the vertical alignment of the second span?

Comment: maybe because it is a html entity and not a "real space"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confused how the `vertical-align` property works. **It doesn't apply to block-level elements.** When it is set on a non-table-cell and non-inline element, the property is actually applied to all the inline text inside that element, *not* to the element itself.

When you use a regular space, the space isn't actually "rendered" by the browser because it's not really content. Therefore, the entire box becomes the line of text (since you're displaying it as inline-block) and the *baseline* is set at the very bottom of the parent against the black border at the bottom, which is why the text appears way down there.

When you use a non-breaking space, the space *is* content and does get render, which moves the baseline for the text up to where the text would actually appear inside the blue box. It's not actually *centering* the text. It's nowhere near centered on my screen. The baseline has just moved based on the content. You'll notice [from this example](http://jsfiddle.net/YbTzT/) that it also changes the line-height of the continuing text.

An easy way to fix this is to float the blue box to the left and then manually set a line-height for the rest of the text to follow. [See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VEvWh/)

```
<div style="height: 40px; line-height: 40px; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 1em 2em;">
    <span style="background-color: Blue; height: 30px; width: 30px; margin: 5px 1em; float: left;"></span>
    <span>Some text that continues on and on and on sothat you can see what is actually happening here blah blah blah blah blah</span>
</div>​
```

Comment: In your div style you have line-height in there twice.  Is that intentional?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when the styled span has rendered content then it sets the baseline for the entire DIV. Is that right? 

I poked around a bit and setting baseline is much more complex than I had realized. So I guess I need to educate myself about that.

Comment: @breischl: It is a bit complicated to understand in this specific context. Basically, you have two inline elements and the thing is their baselines always have to match up. Since you're applying a lot of random styles and such to the inline-block, it's fiddling a lot with your baseline. When there's no content inside it, it messes with it even more.

Answer (score 0):

The entity `&nbsp;` stands for **non breaking space** and is a variant of the space char.
They aren't the same.

In fact the entity prevents an automatic line break

Read more about at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Moreover, the white space result as an "empty" span and that will cause that "bad behaviour"

Answer (score 0):

May help?:

http://jsfiddle.net/mFryV/18/