# Image Will Not Show Up Next To Text

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

```
<div id="banner">
  <h1 class="title">Sam Clark</h1> <img src="Images/twitter.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" id="twitter-img" />
  </div>
```

The image shows up on a new line... How do I stop this?
BTW, I just realized that i dont't need it horizontally centered... sorry.

Comment: Change the <h1> to a span, or set a display:inline for the style on the H1.  Without actually doing it, that's my best guess.

Comment: Can someone look over my code in Firebug or something? I just need some help on cleaning it up/making it work...
http://www.samclark.tk/bio

Answer (score 2):

An `<h1>` element is a block-level element, which means it will take up the enter width by default. If you want the image to show up on the same line with the text, you need to define it *inside* the element, with the text.

```
<h1 align="center" class="title">
    Sam Clark <img src="Images/twitter.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" id="twitter-img" />
</h1>
```

If you're trying to float the image to the left or right, you need to define it *before* the `<h1>` element.

---

After some playing, I was able to find a way to vertically center the text next to your image while also maintaining the horizontal centering of the text inside the header itself, but it involves adding an additional (non-semantic) element.

```
<h1 class="title">
    <span><img src="Images/twitter.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" id="twitter-img" /> Sam Clark</span>
</h1>
```

```css
h1.title {
    text-align: center;
}
h1.title span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 35px;
}
h1.title span img {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yp55G/)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. But now my text isn't aligned vertically with the image.

Comment: align="center" is best in css with verticle-align:middle; or in this case use line-height:some%;

Comment: @SamClark: PS if you don't want it horizontally centered, you can just remove that `text-align: center` CSS rule and it will align to the left instead.

Answer (score 0):

`h1` by default shows up with a `display` value of `block`. To change this use this CSS:

```
#banner .h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` elements are block level elements. You can either select a non-block level element (e.g. `<span>`) or change the style of the `<h1>` element and set `display:inline;`.

Ex:

```
#banner h1.title {
    display: inline;
}
```

Another option is to put your image within the `<h1>` tag and then set the vertical-align property of the image to middle.

```
<div id="banner">
  <h1 align="center" class="title">Sam Clark <img src="Images/twitter.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" id="twitter-img" style="vertical-align:middle" /></h1>
</div>​
```

Comment: The vertical-align:middle just made the text vertically center over the bottom edge of the div...

Comment: I'm not sure what the rest of your HTML and CSS looks like, but given the code above it seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nfa7Y/

Comment: Ughhh, please don't encourage people to [improperly use the `vertical-align` property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10233785/).